# span element tag only changes 1 number instantly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have the "ShackTot" variable automatically update on-screen when the "Buy Reputation" button is pressed.

It should work similarly to how the "Cash" variable decreases as the "Buy Shack" button is clicked where the "Cash" on-screen automatically decreases when the "Buy Shack" button is clicked.

The "ShackTot" variable **does** decrease as the "Buy Reputation" button is clicked but you **need** to click the "Buy Shack" button for it to update on-screen.

```js
var Cash = 150000;

var ShackCost = 50;
var Shack = 0;
var ShackTot = 0;
var ShackTotCost1 = 50;
var ShackOut = 1;

var Reputation = 0;
var ReputationCost = 1;
var ReputationTot = 0;
var ReputationTotCost1 = 1;

function buyShack() {
  if (Cash >= ShackCost) {
    Cash = Cash - ShackCost;
    Shack = Shack + 1;
    ShackCost = Math.round(ShackCost * 1);
    ShackCount = Shack;
    ShackTotCost1 = ShackCost;

    document.getElementById("Cash").innerHTML = Cash;
    document.getElementById("ShackTot").innerHTML = ShackCount;
    // document.getElementById("ShackTotCost").innerHTML = ShackTotCost1;
  }
}

function buyReputation() {
  if (Shack >= ReputationCost) {
    Shack = Shack - ReputationCost;
    Reputation = Reputation + 1;
    ReputationCost = Math.round(ReputationCost * 1);
    ReputationCount = Reputation;
    ReputationTotCost1 = ReputationCost;
    ShackCount = Shack;

    document.getElementById("ReputationTot").innerHTML = ReputationCount;
    // document.getElementById("ReputationTotCost").innerHTML = ReputationTotCost1;
    document.getElementById("ShackTot").innerHTML = ShackCount;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Cash: <span id="Cash">150000</span></h1>
<h1>Shacks: <span id="ShackTot">0</span></h1>
<h1>Reputation: <span id="ReputationTot">0</span></h1>

<button onclick="buyShack()">Buy Shack</button>
<button onclick="buyReputation()">Buy Reputation</button>
```

Comment: There is no ShackTot variable in the code you posted. Only a ShackTotCost1 variable and an element with the id ShackTot. An element with an id is not a variable.

Comment: @cloned the specific issue they were seeing is that ReputationTotCost does not exist, and the fact that doesn't exist causes `document.getElementById("ReputationTotCost").innerHTML = ReputationTotCost1;` to error out which stops `document.getElementById("ShackTot").innerHTML = ShackCount;` from running in `buyReputation()` whereas `ShackTotCost` not existing only causes an error and everything carries on running. However @Dali's edit of the code has stopped the code from being wrong in the first place, which kind of breaks the question.